# Parsing weird path from Runtastic to proper map path

Tags: php, apache, http, encoding, maps

I am working with this repo:
https://github.com/timoschlueter/php-runtastic

And it gives me map path in weird form, like this:
https://static-maps.runtastic.com/static-map/?style=mapnik&color=&width=500&height=300&path=q%7DhtHuqqlB%3FWg%40%7DIoFbFGtKhE~BtAwJg%40iKqEvE_%40hKv%40xDfE%7BANaLkBqFyDfHv%40~JvEYNeK%7D%40sHgEtFH%60Kn%40xDfEaCDeKoAwGcEhGFfJfC~HlCjElDjEXkJ%40cKgCGgAqEHoJ%7DElB_AfKd%40zE~DCj%40sJ]mJaFlEC~JbDrEzAuIPwKaFfAiArJzChI~BmIFaMrDwCIcF&weight=4

Do you know maybe how to decode this format to GPS coordinates or something like that?

Comment: RunTastic, as far as I know, doesn't actually store GPS co-ordinates per se, but rather a [polyline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) with additional information that's then drawn on top of a map.

Comment: I found this online converter:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility
but the map is very inaccurate and points to multiple coordinates that original map doesn't.
Also, I've tried with many repos as:
https://github.com/emcconville/google-map-polyline-encoding-tool
still very inaccurate, pointing around the proper location, someone maybe knows what can be the problem?